# Does "instead" make sense here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

> The truck driver accelerates toward the man. The man dives out of the
> way to avoid the truck, which **instead** goes on to crash into a
> tree.

Would you include "instead" as I have done or does it seem wrong to you?

(Note: The truck driver is deliberately trying to run the man over with his truck)

Answer (score 1):

I think the "instead" there captures part of what you want to say: the truck hit the tree rather than the man.

Whether it sounds right or needed really depends on the full context - the actual surrounding sentences you summarize in the Note.